# Using Lightroom as external editor for iPhoto, how to save image back to iPhoto

Tags: photos.app, adobe-lightroom

I setup iPhoto to use Lightroom 5 as the external editor. Now when I open an image in iPhoto and click edit, it opens in Lightroom and asks me to import the image. Once I click import and make my edits, there is no option to save. I must export the image to some folder and drag/drop it back into iPhoto (which means I now have a duplicate).

Is there an easy way to make quick edits in Lightroom and just save over the original file so the original is updated automatically in iPhoto?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I found several posts that explain why using LR as an external editor cannot be seamless (here's an example: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1463251). This explanation makes sense to me for now. If I find something better I will update this reply.

I don't shoot RAW all the time, so when I do here's my workflow:

1. Copy RAW files from card to desktop folder
2. Import (Add) to LR and edit
3. Export from LR to 'temp' desktop folder as JPEG files
4. Import JPEG files to iPhoto

** If I want to keep the original RAW files, I move the folder of originals, still on my desktop, to an external storage drive. If I don't need the originals, I can delete this folder.