# Syncing photos to iCloud and managing them with Lightroom

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app, adobe-lightroom

I am a brand new Mac user, having recently purchased an iMac updated to OSX 10.10.3. I also have installed Adobe Lightroom 5, and I have a bunch of photos synced to iCloud and available through the Photos app.

I would like to be able to manage my photos through Lightroom, but have the photos synced through iCloud with my other devices. However, it appears that Lightroom cannot read the "Photos Library.photolibrary" file that is created with the Photos app.

I have seen [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/144413/121420) regarding the iPhoto app and Lightroom. Does this still apply for the Photos app?

What options are available to be able to sync my with my other devices and still be able to manage them on the iMac with Lightroom?

Comment: Given that Photos literally launched yesterday, it is unlikely Lightroom would be able to read the library file even if it is possible to do so. Lightroom would require an update to support the new software, if that is something that Adobe wants it to be able to do.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It is all new to me. This is my first foray into Apple OS's. I had no idea that Photos happened to be new to everyone else too. I will keep an eye out if Adobe releases any updates.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution:

1. create a symbolic link to your iCloud folder from the terminal window
   ln -s ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs iCloudDrive
2. This creates a link from your home folder to your iCloud documents
3. Now open up Lightroom and you should be able to navigate to the linked folder and import directly from there.